# Can I use a map with my custom tiles in Android for asset tracking in free plan?

Tags: android, google-maps, tile

Google Android terms and conditions prohibits using maps for asset tracking by their free plan.

Google supports supports removing Google Maps tiles from the map and add custom ones. It is a straightforward, well supported and easy task.

What if I don't use the Google map tiles, just GoogleMap mapping **component** to show tiles owned and developed by me? Is it allowed by their free plan for asset tracking or not?

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE:** finally I could have a phone call with an expert from Google, and according to his explanation we can **not** use free plan for this purpose.

Comment: I think asset tracking always requires Premium plan license independently of tile providers in your application. If I understand correctly the asset tracking solution might use heavily web services to resolve GPS coordinates to places, so the Premium plan is because of amount of requests that these type of solutions send to Google servers.

Comment: As I see only one server request is made toward Google servers: at first startup of the app. Later it works even if I remove API key from the app, because I don't need anything from Google, I don't make any requests toward their server, I just need its map component on Android to show my tiles.

Comment: I'm google developers experts for Google Maps API, and I asked similar question to the Google Maps API team directly, and their answer was the same as @xomena. So, if you just need map component to show your tiles, I recommend to use alternative SDKs, such as mapbox. https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/

Comment: You can also check Terms of Service [paragraph 10.4 c (iv)](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms?hl=es#10-license-restrictions), it reads `No asset-tracking unless you have purchased the applicable enterprise license.`

Comment: Thanks to all! Yep, @xomena, I have read it, but it was not clear for me that it is for the mapping component or for the map data, or both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about asset tracking than obviously you need to use some sort of apis to track your asset and that will be free for limited period, Depends on the usage. Focusing on the word **Tracking**

I was having the same kind of situation where I need to put track my asset based on distance, updating their location on realtime and all. All the aspect that are coming under asset tracking.

I came to an conclusion that as far as it is limited to testing you can do that with Free limits. But once you have the bigger plan for implementation google provide its premium plan.

These plans are for number of assets you are using and pricing is depending on that. The API hits for tracking the assets are unlimited in that case.

You can check the official information for asset tracking

https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/enterprise.google.com/en//maps/files/asset_tracking_with_premium_plan.pdf

https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer!